# Accessing Geopoints using Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called *posts* in Firestore which contains a documents with the fields *content* and *location*. Content is a `string` and Location is a `Geopoint`.

When accessing the database using Firebase Cloud Functions, I am able to print out the content by adding it into an array and `JSON.stringfy` the whole thing as a response.

```
  db.collection("posts").get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {

        var element = {
          "content": doc.data().content,
        }
        query = query.concat(element);
    });
    res.send(JSON.stringify(query));
```

However, If i try to emulate this with the geopoints, I simply get an empty response `{}`.

```
  db.collection("posts").get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        var latitude = doc.data().location.getLatitude();
        var longitude = doc.data().location.getLongitude();

        var element = {
          "latitude": latitude,
          "longitude": longitude,
        }
        query = query.concat(element);
    });
    res.send(JSON.stringify(query));
```

How do access the Geopoint values in the Firestore using Javascript so I can perform operations on/print them? i.e. find distance between two points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this by accessing the latitude/longitude fields directly using `doc.data().location.latitude`.